# Post a BLOB image using Ajax and receive using Spring Boot

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to post an BLOB image using ajax. But spring controller is receiving a null value instead.

Here is my controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadAvatar", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody List<Long> uploadAvatar(byte[] avatar) {
    // avatar is null here

    // do some stuff
}
```

And here is the ajax part.

```
    var avatar = // some BLOB data
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('fname', 'avatar.png');
    fd.append('avatar', avatar);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/uploadAvatar',
        type: 'POST',
        data: fd,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: applySuggestions,
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

you need MultipartFile to receive file.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadAvatar", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody List<Long> uploadAvatar(@RequestParam MultipartFile  avatar) {
    byte[] bytes = avatar.getBytes();
}
```